# Separate DB just for JUnit tests in Spring app

Tags: spring, junit, persistence

I am writing unit tests for my Spring application using in-file HSQL db. I don't want to   pollute this db with test data, so I am trying to set up another in-memory HSQL db instance to be used in tests.

In my abstract testing class I import test application context XML configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/testingContext.xml")
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractDaoForTesting {
```

**testingContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    ">


    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" />


        <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.se.micom" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
  <bean id="characteristicDao" class="com.se.micom.dao.CharacteristicDaoImpl"/>
  <bean id="functionalityDao" class="com.se.micom.dao.FunctionalityDaoImpl"/>
  <bean id="segmentDao" class="com.se.micom.dao.SegmentDaoImpl"/>
  <bean id="segmentService" class="com.se.micom.service.SegmentServiceImpl"/>
  <bean id="functionalityService" class="com.se.micom.service.FunctionalityServiceImpl"/>
  <bean id="characteristicService" class="com.se.micom.service.CharacteristicServiceImpl" />
</beans>
```

Up to now in-memory HSQL db is working fine in test.

However, as soon as I introduce in my project `persistence.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF` unit tests start to use this persistence unit and not the one from `testingContext.xml`.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

  <persistence-unit name="micomPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.se.micom.dao.domain.Characteristic</class>
    <class>com.se.micom.dao.domain.Functionality</class>
    <class>com.se.micom.dao.domain.Segment</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:\workspace_java\Micom2\db\micom"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What's wrong with this configuration? Why tests "prefer" to use db defined in `persistence.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a perfect example for Spring profiles. It is always problematic to have multiple beans doing the same thing in your context at once if you want a certain one to be used.

You should have two different profiles, `"prod"` and `"test"`, and wrap your bean declaration in the xml config accordingly with `<beans profile="XYZ"> ... </beans>`. A more extensive example can be found [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml).

You can then annotate your test with `@Profile("test")` and it should use the correct database.